# Error using set of custom class

Tags: c++

When I try to compile the following code, I get

```
'const elem' is not derived from 'const std::__cxx11::sub_match<_BiIter>'
```

I don't understand what it means and what is wrong with my code?

```
struct elem
{
    int x,y,val;
    elem(int x,int y,int val)
    {
        this->x = x;
        this->y = y;
        this->val = val;
    }
    bool operator<(const elem b)
    {
        return val > b.val;
    }
};


int kthSmallest(int v[MAX][MAX], int n, int k)
{
    set<pair<int,int>> m;
    priority_queue<elem, vector<elem>> pq;
    int temp = k;
    pq.emplace(0,0,v[0][0]);
    while(temp != 0)
    {
        temp--;
        if(pq.top().x + 1 < n && m.find(make_pair(pq.top().x + 1, pq.top().y)) == m.end())
        {
            m.insert(make_pair(pq.top().x + 1, pq.top().y));
            pq.emplace(pq.top().x + 1, pq.top().y, v[pq.top().x + 1][pq.top().y]);
        }
        if(pq.top().y + 1 < n && m.find(make_pair(pq.top().x + 1, pq.top().y)) == m.end())
        {
            m.insert(make_pair(pq.top().x, pq.top().y + 1));
            pq.emplace(pq.top().x, pq.top().y + 1, v[pq.top().x][pq.top().y + 1]);
        }
    }
    return pq.top().val;
}
```

Comment: Declare the operator like bool operator<(const elem &b) const { /*...*/ }

Comment: I get a pretty nice error from Clang: *prog.cc:18:10: note: candidate function not viable: 'this' argument has type 'const elem', but method is not marked const ... 
    bool operator<(const elem b)*

Comment: @chris no such error in gcc

Comment: I get a pretty nice error from GCC HEAD: */opt/wandbox/gcc-head/include/c++/8.0.0/bits/stl_function.h:386:20: error: no match for 'operator<' (operand types are 'const elem' and 'const elem')
       { return __x < __y; }
                ~~~~^~~~~
prog.cc:18:10: note: candidate: 'bool elem::operator<(elem)' <near match>
     bool operator<(const elem b)
          ^~~~~~~~
prog.cc:18:10: note:   passing 'const elem\*' as 'this' argument discards qualifiers* - It's not as nice as Clang's (especially stuffed into a comment), but points to your comparison with a helpful hint about `const`.

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked.

Comment: @chris How do you know what the error is from that(the gcc one)?

Comment: @kendall, It explicitly mentions your compare function as a near match (*candidate: 'bool elem::operator<(elem)' <near match> bool operator<(const elem b)*) and explains why it couldn't be used (*passing 'const elem\*' as 'this' argument discards qualifiers*, i.e., the function is not const-correct)

Answer (score 1):

Third template argument of `std::priority_queue` is `Compare` - binary operator which is by default [std::less](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/functional/less/). It needs both arguments as `const`. Your first argument of `operator<` (which is by default object on which you call it) is not `const` because the method is not `const`. That is why you need to change it as pointed out in comments:

```
bool operator<(const elem b) const
{
    return val > b.val;
}
```